# REST API resource creation

Tags: rest, api

I'm developing REST API. There is'Users' and 'Tasks'resources and each user is able to create 'UserTask'. So, what kind of URL is in line with REST API standards and conventions? Wich approach is more logical In the end?

```
post: users/{id}/tasks
```

or

```
post: tasks/users/{id}
```

does it make sense to have both?

I have read lots of topics about it but found nothing that could be helpful in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a *task* belongs to a particular *user*, I would go for:

```
POST /users/{user-id}/tasks
```

To get a representation of a particular *task*, you could use:

```
GET /users/{user-id}/tasks/{task-id}
```

Comment: Thank you Casio, see my additional question below please

Comment: @VasyaFortochkin I would have different controllers to handle this.

Comment: @VasyaFortochkin If my answer suit your needs, please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick next to my answer :)

Comment: Ok. I'll wait a while and if nobody give me better answer I'll click the tick :)

Comment: @cassiomolin How about if I need to query all the 10 latest tasks created by all users. How would you organize your resource in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you might consider Object orient philosophy, Then user will perform task and not task have users.

So you can consider using this : `post: users/{id}/tasks`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Folowing this should UserService contains method 'createTask' or I can use TaskService? Because in this case i get "overload" User Service + Controller and thin Task Service+Controller. It makes me think maybe I do something wrong..